# Контейнеры, созданные в docker-compose.yml, постоянно включаются автоматически

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Попробовал использовать не настоящую БД, а находящуюся в контейнере. Нашёл в интернете пример файла **docker-compose.yml** и скопипастил себе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге всё работает. Я не сразу, но обратил внимание на проблему: теперь у меня 2 указанных контейнера работают всегда. То есть закрываю студию IDEA, перезагружаю комп, и вижу 2 работающих контейнера (они отображаются прямо в файловом менеджере Dolphin):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее я открываю терминал, и останавливаю эти контейнеры руками:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого они и в файловом менеджере пропадают:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее я вообще IDEA не запускаю. Просто опять перезагружаю комп, и 2 контейнера опять запущены. Мне вообще казалось, что когда я закрываю проект в IDEA, то по логике все контейнеры должны остановиться. Я что-то наверное не так делаю. Я пока только основные консольные команды Docker освоил. Docker-compose только начал разбираться, и сходу такая проблема.

Кто-нибудь может подсказать, от чего проблема?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас в `docker-compose` написано: `restart: always` что собственно и говорит о том, что контейнера будет автоматически перезапускаться когда он остановился (не важно сам упал или его пользователь остановил, перезагрузил машину), уберите эту опцию и они не будут сами запускаться.

Также есть опция: `restart: unless-stopped`, которая говорит о том, что их не нужно рестартовать в случае, когда пользователь сам его остановил, но если контейнер упал, то он все равно будет перезапущен.

[docker-compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#restart).

[docker restart policy docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#use-a-restart-policy).

Comment: интересно, что топикстартер даже не читал, что он там скопировал из интернета.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov  да я просто на тот момент только начал знакомиться с Докер, поэтому ничего не понимал, что там написано)